# Stuck completing my first rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview, actioncontroller

I was taking a [tutorial](http://www.codelearn.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial/introducing-controller-view-routes) online on rails but I got stuck. These are my controller and view files:

`/app/controllers/todos_controller.rb`:

```
class TodosController < ApplicationController
  def index
  @todo_array = [ "Buy Milk", "Buy Soap", "Pay bill", "Draw Money" ]

  end
end
```

`/app/views/todos/index.html.erb`:

```
<title>Shared Todo App </title>
<h1>Shared Todo App</h1>
<p>All your todos here</p>
<ul>
  <% @todo_array.each do |t| %>
   <li> #todo item here </li>
   <% end %>
</ul>
```

I need to change the code `#todo item here` to show the actual todo item from the array. So I get output as:

```
Shared Todo App

All your todos here

 - Buy Milk 
 - Buy Soap
 - Pay bill
 - Draw Money
```

Comment: `<% @todo_array.each do |t| %>
   <li> <%= t %> </li>
   <% end %>`

Comment: <% @todo_array.each do |t| %> <li> <%= t %> </li> <% end %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<title>Shared Todo App </title>
<h1>Shared Todo App</h1>
<p>All your todos here</p>
<ul>
  <% @todo_array.each do |t| %>
    <li> <% t %> </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

But since you're getting stuck on that part, I suggest you start with a different tutorial or book, something that explains a bit more about what you're doing and why.  http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

Answer (score 0):

Instance variables in your controller are passed as instance variables in your view.

**Controller:**

```
@todo_array = [ "Buy Milk", "Buy Soap", "Pay bill", "Draw Money" ]
```

**View:**

```
<% @todo_array.each do |t| %>
   <li> <%= t %> </li>
   <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the comment by `<%= t %>`. Rails will automatically display each value of the array :

```
<% @todo_array.each do |t| %>
    <li><%= t %></li>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the tutorial and the little ruby demo it was mentioned that 
**Accessing each element of array using blocks. `arr.each { |a| puts a }` prints all the elements of the array.**

However you need to just pass `<%= t %>` in place of comment.

So your final piece of code will be:

```
  <% @todo_array.each do |t| %>
    <li> <%= t %> </li>
  <% end %>
```